ckeditor addListToDropdown not showing label
editor.ui.componentFactory.add("InsertDropDown", locale => {

     //const dropdown = createDropdown(locale);
     const items = new Collection();
     items.add({
         type: 'button',
         model: new Model({
             withText: true,
             label: 'First item',
             labelStyle: 'color: red'
         })
     });

     items.add({
         type: 'button',
         model: new Model({
             withText: true,
             label: 'Second item',
             labelStyle: 'color: green',
             class: 'foo'
         })
     });

     items.add({
         type: 'button',
         model: new Model({
             withText: true,
             label: 'Second item',
             labelStyle: 'color: green',
             class: 'foo'
         })
     });


     const dropdown = createDropdown(locale);
     dropdown.buttonView.set({
         withText: true,
         label: "choose variable",
         tooltip: true
     });
     addListToDropdown(dropdown, items);
     return dropdown;
 })

this is the code which i am trying
ckeditor version ckeditor5/42.0.0
using cdn


well, isnt thelabel "choose variant" shown? how´d u expect it to look?

@johnSmith i am expecting to show First item & second item in the yellow bar

ah okay lol, i thought the yellow bars were some censorship haha .... Actually i´m having the similiar code and it is working, i just dont have the labelStyle and class properties.. maybe check element inspector if there is some css overriding its color to white or similiar?

@johnsmit Please let me know the version you are using

my feature is currently working on v40.1.0 you can see the code i use here it should be almost the same

same error for me. tried both version 42.0.0 and 42.0.1.

From the version 41.x the Model has changed to ViewModel
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/updating/guides/update-to-41.html
items.add({
     type: 'button',
     model: new ViewModel({
         withText: true,
         label: 'Second item',
         labelStyle: 'color: green',
         class: 'foo'
     })
 });

